# Modify existing wordpress site using react js, redux js, wp-api

Tags: wordpress, performance, reactjs, redux, single-page-application

I have created a Wordpress site using buddy press(to manage members and etc), here is the link: designers.printedvillage.com.

I feel as we move ahead and plans of making this website faster and more dyanmic wanted to transform this site into react and redux. I cannot move away from Wordpress as there is a lot of data at stake.
So just wanted some guidance on what should I do to make this website single page application, if I use react with wordpress would I be able to use plugins?

Is there any other options? open for all the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Most plugins don't have rest api support, but some of the major plugins I use do such as:

- Advanced Custom Fields
- Tribe Events Calendar
- Gravity Forms
- WooCommerce

For the plugins that don't support the API, I was able to pretty easily create a custom endpoint to send whatever data was needed to React. (read more about this here: https://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/)

Good luck on the migration, and happy coding!